# React-admin change EditButton, get request

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am fairly new to `React` and `react-admin`. So far most of the stuff working smoothly. But I want to make the `EditButton` little differently that it gives.

The current request is handled like this:

> localhost/api/posts/26

`EditButton` button called in the `DataGrid` like this

```
const PostsList = ({ permissions, ...props }) => (
  <List
    {...props}    
    filters={<PostsFilter />}    
    sort={{ field: 'name', order: 'ASC' }}    
    actions={<ActionsRefresh />}    
    bulkActions={false}    
  >
    <Datagrid
       {...props}    
        ids={this.state['clasifiers']}    
        hover={false}>   
        <TextField source="id" />    
        <TextField source="name" label="Name" />
         <EditButton />
         </Datagrid>
   </List>
   )

export default ClassifiersList
```

And the respective `index.js` file =>

```
import PostList from './PostList'
import PostEdit from './PostEdit'

export default {
  list: PostList,
  edit: PostEdit
}
```

But I want to pass more parameters to server from this get request, like:

> localhost/api/posts/26/7

OR

> localhost/api/posts/26?status=7

Is there a option to make the `EditButton` request change or do I have to create a custom button and `onClick` view the `EditPost.js` component, this I have no idea about how to do.

Comment: custom button, custom `linkToRecord`

Comment: can you give me a sample @xadm